# Avoid generic arguments

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, expression, func

I have the following extension method which asserts that a property (Id) contains a specified attribute (TV):

```
public static void ShouldHave<T, TV, TT>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TT>> exp) {...}
```

The method can be called like this:

```
MyDto myDto = new MyDto();
myDto.ShouldHave<MyDto, RequiredAttribute, int>(x => x.Id);
```

Compiles just fine. I was wondering if it is possible to remove T and TT from the method signature. T because ShouldHave is called on T why it shouldn't be necessary to specify it explicitly. And TT is the type of the property referenced in the expression (x.Id).

Comment: What's the point of `TV` (the second generic parameter)?

Comment: It's the type of the required attribute.

Comment: @ba__friend:  Look again, there's three of 'em.

Comment: I know, but look at his call definition and then read the first sentence of his post. TV => Attritube to match.

Comment: @ba__friend: That's more likely a typo.  There are three parameters, two of them (`T` and `TT`) are used in the signature.  `TV` is completely unnecessary in this context.

Comment: @Jeff: How can you know this? There could be a line `if (someVar is TV) {...}` in the implementation of `ShouldHave`.

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes but the contents of the function was omitted.  That is why I asked my question in the first place.

Comment: @Jeff: As I understood the first sentence of the question, the point is to check whether a field property declaration contains some attribute (Example: `<RequiredAttribute()> public int Id {get; set;}`). The concrete implementation of the function is irrelevant to the question, but it's quite obvious (at least to me) that the type of the attribute in question is required.

Comment: @Heinzi: Ah that's the part I missed from the question.  Thanks for clearing that up.  The wording could have been better.  :)

Comment: The TV is used in the method body through reflection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic inference of type arguments only works if *no* generic arguments are specified in the method call. I.e., this:

```
myDto.ShouldHave<, RequiredAttribute, >(x => x.Id);
```

is not valid syntax. You can either have "all or nothing".

Thus, if you want to infer `T` and `TT`, you need to pass the information currently contained in `TV` in some other way. For example, one option would be to pass the *type* of the attribute as a parameter:

```
public static void ShouldHave<T, TT>(this T obj, 
                                     Expression<Func<T, TT>> exp, 
                                     Type attribute) {...}
```

(Obviously, this will require changes in your implementation of ShouldHave).

Then you should be able to call the method like this:

```
MyDto myDto = new MyDto();
myDto.ShouldHave(x => x.Id, typeof(RequiredAttribute));
```

Comment: I choose your proposal with a slight modification: public static void ShouldHave<T, TT>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TT>> exp, params Type[] attributes)

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles:

```
public static void ShouldHave<T, TT>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TT>> exp)
{...}

MyDto myDto = new MyDto();
myDto.ShouldHave(x => x.Id);
```

This omits the `TV` type argument, which is the reason for your need to explicitly specify the generic arguments at the call site. If you need this argument then you’re out of luck.

Comment: But `T` and `TT` are not removed

Comment: @oliholz Yes they are, at the call site. Who cares whether they are still necessary in the definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void ShouldHave<TV>(this object obj, Expression<Func<object, object>> exp) {...}
```

You should find that `exp` now consists of the real expression surrounded by a cast to object. Inside your method, strip off the cast as follows:

```
Expression realExp = ((UnaryExpression) exp).Operand;
```

Then you can start analysing the expression. You will have to do more runtime tests and safety checks than your original method though.